# How could I define pairs for a User model?

Tags: activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a User model, and I would like to pair users. So user1 can be paired with user2. I want to store these relationships in a separate model named Pair. This Pair model has 2 integer attributes: `user_id` and `pair_id`. Both will contain ids from the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pair
end

class Pair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  belongs_to :pair, foreign_key: 'pair_id'
end
```

This allows me to do this:

```
User.first.pair
```

And I get an instance of the Pair model.

But if I want to get the pair directly in one step I have to do this:

```
User.first.pair.pair
```

Which seems ugly. **Is there any better way to do it?**

As a bonus, it would be AMAZING to be able to do this:

```
User.first.pair = User.last
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the double pair call, we could redefine the association in the User model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :pair_record, class_name: 'Pair'
  has_one :pair, through: :pair_record
end
```

This way you can do things like these:

```
u1 = User.find(1)
u2 = User.find(2)

u1.pair = u2
u1.pair # -> u2
```